# Compiling Pysnmp with Py2exe

Tags: python, pysnmp

I've created a program that pulls information from routers using SNMP (via PySNMP module). The application works great and I now what to compile it into a standalone application so that I can distribute it to my co-workers. However, after trying both Py2exe and PyInstaller, I've been unsuccessful in compiling a working application. I have searched the internet (a lot!) trying to find an example of someone who has successfully been able to compile their PySNMP application, but haven't been able to find anyway. Is there a better way to compile this or am I just doing it wrong?

These are the modules I've imported:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
```

This is the setup.py I've created for Py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup( console = [
               { "script": "RSSIChecker.py", 
               }],
       options = { 
            "py2exe":{
                'includes': [                
                    'pysnmp.smi.mibs.*',                
                    'pysnmp.smi.mibs.instances.*'                
                    ]            
            }        
        }
)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With the following [setup.py](http://snmpsim.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/snmpsim/snmpsim/setup.py?view=markup), a pysnmp-based app can be packaged with py2exe right out of the box (see line 101 and below). There are also some additional modules added implicitly into py2exe packaging as they are used by the app, not pysnmp itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Apologies, I've only just started coding so I'm a little confused. Am I supposed to use that entire file as my setup.py or just from lines 101 onwards? I downloaded the entire file and ran:

python setup.py py2exe

This threw some errors about missing files which I found in the parent directory of the link you sent. With all files downloaded, the compiling completed, but my .exe file wasn't in the 'dist' folder. The only files were:

datafile.exe
mib2dev.exe
pcap2dev.exe
snmprec.exe
snmpsimd.exe
w9xpopen.exe

Am I missing something? Is there any helpful info I can provide?